# Problem with Time Synchronisation in 5G and 2,4G Packet Lag measurment

Tags: python, time, server, jupyter-notebook, client-server

I have to compare the lag in a server-client model in 2,4G and 5G.

My anticipation is that 5G is faster than the 2,4G by a large margin. I have already taken the 5G measurments. The average lag turned out to be 40.2ms -which is above what I was predicting-. The issue beacme visible when I tried the same with the 2,4G setup, and the lag was calculated to be a negative value. The two computers on which I was running the codes werent really synchronised. I would appriciate any input on how I would solve this issue.

I wrote the code on Jupyter as a Notebook.

Below you can find powerpoints of the setups used and the respective code used for the client and the server. The results displayed are in micro seconds.

**5G Setup**
[image]

**2,4G Setup**
[image]

**Server Code:**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from datetime import datetime

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import csv
import time
from time import sleep
from decimal import Decimal


# In[2]:


test = 1


# In[3]:


#create csv. file to append data

file_name = "2.4G_Time_Data_" + str(test)

test = test + 1

print(file_name)

with open(file_name+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as time_file:

    spamwriter = csv.writer(time_file, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    
    spamwriter.writerow(['Packet','Lag(uS)'])
    


# In[ ]:


#start running a server, saves the in coming data in a csv file

received_package = 0

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/postjson', methods = ['POST'])

def postJsonHandler():
    
    global received_package
    received_package = received_package + 1
    
    print(request.is_json)
    
    content = request.get_json()
    
    print (content)
    
    now = datetime.now();
    
    time = content["time"]
    
    time_now =  datetime.timestamp(now)
    
    print("Sent : " + str(time))
    
    print("Received : " + str(time_now) )
    
    delta_time = (time_now - time) * (10**6) # in micro seconds
    
    print("Packet Travel Time(s) : " + str(delta_time) )
    
    with open(file_name+'.csv', 'a') as f:
        
        writer = csv.writer(f)
    
        writer.writerow([str(received_package), str(delta_time)])
    
    return 'JSON Received'

    

app.run(host = '0.0.0.0' , port = 8090)
```

**Client Code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import signal
from time import sleep
import time

import os
import sys
import json

sample_size = 1000

for i in range(sample_size) :

    now = datetime.now()

    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ":" + str(now.microsecond)

    #time = str(now)

    timestamp = datetime.timestamp(now)

    requests.post('http://myIP:8090/postjson', json={'time': timestamp})
    
    print ("Estimated size: " + str(sys.getsizeof(json) / 1024) + "KB")
    
    sleep(0.1)
```

**My 2.4G Measurment**

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about networking and not about software development.

Comment: @KlausD. so where should I post it?